# Generate DOM elements from prototype JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to generate elements in DOM from several prototypes I have defined earlier.
I considered using a factory to choose a default prototype and adding some extra features.
My question is, do I need to instantiate a class each time and parse an object into the DOM with a parse()-class method? Or is there a better way, for example having only static methods for this process?

This is my class way right now:

```
function Window(params) {
  this.id = this.createNewWindowID();
  this.name = params.name;
  this.type = params.type;
  this.dims = params.dims;

}
Window.prototype.parse = function() {
  $("#windowarea").append('<div class="content-window uk-panel uk-panel-box toolbox-tools" id="' + this.id + '">' +
    '<div class="uk-panel-header uk-panel-title content-window-header">' + this.name +
    '<i class="fa fa-times pull-right close-panel"></i>' +
    '<i class="fa pull-right fa-chevron-down toggle-panel"></i></div></div>');
  $('#' + this.id).css({
    "top": this.dims.top,
    "left": this.dims.left,
    "width": this.dims.width,
    "height": this.dims.height
  });
  $('#' + this.id).draggable({
    handle: ".uk-panel-header",
    drag: function(evt, el) {
      el.position.left = Math.max(0, el.position.left);
      el.position.top = Math.max(0, el.position.top);
    },
    stop: function(evt, el) {
      var index = getWindowIndex('id', this.id);
      allwindows[index].dims.top = el.position.top;
      allwindows[index].dims.left = el.position.left;
      if (storage) {
        localStorage.windowcontent = JSON.stringify(allwindows);
      }
    }
  }).resizable({
    handles: "e, w, s, se",
    resize: function(evt, el) {
      el.size.width = Math.max(200, el.size.width);
      el.size.height = Math.max(10, el.size.height);
    },
    stop: function(evt, el) {
      var index = getWindowIndex('id', this.id);
      allwindows[index].dims.width = el.size.width;
      allwindows[index].dims.height = el.size.height;
      if (storage) {
        localStorage.windowcontent = JSON.stringify(allwindows);
      }
    }
  });
  switch (this.type) {
    case "topview":
     new View($('#' + this.id));
      break;
    case "sideview":
      $('#' + this.id).append('<div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge">Dies wird eine Sideview</div>');
      new View($('#' + this.id));
      break;
    default:
      if (this.content != undefined) {
        $('#' + this.id).append(this.content);
      }
  }
};
```

Thanks for ideas. Please let me know if this is described well enough..

fwerre

EDIT:
Ok, let me describe my project a bit more precisely.

My objects are windows, which are draggable and resizable (from jquery-ui). Windows can also be added and removed from the screen.
The number of windows plus their sizes, positions and contents shall be stored in localStorage. On browser reload or restart, the window setup shall be restored from the localStorage-JSON-object.

I think I only need a method to put the window parameters together and eventually add them to the DOM. How do I best organize these methods?

Thanks

Comment: The word "parse" usually means to read some text and return the corresponding objects. It looks like your `parse()` method does the opposite.

Comment: What's best depends on how you intend to use the class. If you need to keep each instance around after you add the DOM elements, then you should create an object for each. If you're just using the prototype as a namespace for your functions, you only need one instance.

Comment: And if there's only one instance, you don't need a prototype, just put the functions directly in the object.

Comment: Thats right, parse is maybe a bad name

Comment: I don't need the instance, I just think of putting all objects into a JSON later on

Comment: How would I organize my methods if I need only one instance to generate the objects?

Comment: `Window = { parse: function(params) {... }, otherMethod: function(params) { ...}, ...}`